# Is there a way to secure any view in laravel 5 with htaccess file?

Tags: .htaccess, laravel

I have the links for my site like following

```
http://laravel.test.com/
```

I want to secure the following links by using `.htaccess`

```
http://laravel.test.com/user/print/984
http://laravel.test.com/user/order/print/1215
```

Comment: Don't use `.htaccess`. Use laravel route middleware...http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication#protecting-routes#protecting-routes

Comment: I have already used laravel authentication for rest of links, but need to access the above links from another desktop application.

Comment: Then use [basic authentication](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/authentication#http-basic-authentication)

Comment: Please read this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/51782584/4701635

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend creating a [middleware](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/middleware) over using .htaccess for this.

I'm assuming you will let the user who the order belongs to access the URI, correct? Create a middleware called `PrintOrderMiddleware`.

In the middleware, you make sure that the authenticated user matches the `user_id` on the order. If so, they can access the route.

Another possibility is using [Laravel Authorization](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authorization). It acts much in the same way as Middleware, only you have a bit more control over policies you can set, and isn't specifically designed to guard routes.

---

When you say "secure your views using .htaccess", do you mean block everyone from accessing it, except, say your own IP? If so, just add this:

```
<FilesMatch "^(user/print|user/order/print)$"> 
    order deny,allow
    deny from all
    allow from my.ip.address
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Not block for everyone, but the users who have username and password which we added in **htpasswds** can access those views.

Comment: In that case just add the already active `auth` middleware to the routes