# How in Laravel 5 to allow and deny in .htacces file?

Tags: laravel

this my .htacces file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
# THIS IS NEW
#RewriteBase /

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# THIS IS NEW
#RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
#RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

I want to allow only a few IP that can access my website, is there an alternative way to use other than htacces, I'm very newbie at Laravel please help, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Middleware` is good for restriction of IP.
Create `Middleware` as per following and add a condition for IP, If IP will match then a user will be redirected on 404 otherwise request will continue.

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class IpMiddleware
{

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {

        if ($request->ip() != "111.111.239.119") {
            // here insted checking single ip address we can do collection of ip 
            //address in constant file and check with in_array function
            return redirect('404');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }

}
```

After creating middleware, Need to add this middleware in `app/Http/Kernel.php` in `$middlewareGroups` array.

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\IpMiddleware::class
    ],

    'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
    ],
];
```

Answer (score 0):

use middleware instead of .htaccess.

first fetch the Ip Address from request then

match the Ip Address with saved values inside middleware.

if match is true then allow them to access your website otherwise redirect them to a different page.